# A matrix is diagonalizable iff $\operatorname{Im}(A-xI)\cap \ker (A-xI)=0$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A \in M_n(\mathbb C)$ then prove that A is diagonalizable iff $\operatorname{Im}(A-xI)+ \ker (A-xI)=\mathbb C^n$ for every $x \in \mathbb C$.

My attempt: From rank nullity we see that the second case holds only when $\operatorname{Im}(A-xI)\cap \ker (A-xI)=0$. I need to show that this is the same as saying that there are $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors or that for each eigenvalue, its algebraic multiplicity equals its geometric. Let on the contrary a $x \in \mathbb C$ such that the intersection is not empty and let $v \in \operatorname{Im}(A-xI)\cap \ker (A-xI)$ a non zero vector. Then $Av=xv$ Thus v is an eigenvector and x an eigenvalue. However, $v \in \operatorname{Im}(A-xI)$ so there s a vector $u$ such that $Au-xu=v$. In fact $u$ must be linearly independent of v because otherwise that would imply that $v=0$. Replacing it above, we get $ A(Au-xu)=x(Au-xu) \Rightarrow A^2u-2Axu=x^2u=0 \Rightarrow$ $$(A-xI)^2u=0$$
 Then looking at the ranks I could observe that $\operatorname{rank}(A-xI)^2 \leq n-2$ as both $u$ and $v$ are in the kernel. This should imply that A is not diagonalizable but I m not sure how.  My attempt is to say that if A was diagonalizable, then $A=U^{-1}DU$ where $D$ is diagonal and $(A-xI)^2=U^{-1}(D-xI)^2U$. and therefore $\operatorname{rank}(A-xI)^m=\operatorname{rank}(D-xI)^m$. However, given that $(D-xI)^m$ is just the same diagonal matrix with its non zero entries raised in a power of m, the rank must remain the same, i.e $\operatorname{rank}(D-xI)$ should be equal to $\operatorname{rank}(D-xI)^2$

I feel like I m stepping over some steps or that it could be done in an easier way, so is that correct?

For the other direction, let $x$ be an eigenvalue and  $\operatorname{Im}(A-xI)\cap \ker (A-xI)=0$. Then $\ker(A-xI)$ is the geometric multiplicity of the eigenvalue $x$. I need to show that it s equal to its algebraic, but I m not sure on how to continue....

I d appreciate any hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall a matrix is diagonalizable iff its minimal polynomial factorizes as the product of distinct linears.  If $\operatorname{Im}(A-xI)\cap\ker(A-xI)\neq 0$, then $(t-x)^2$ divides the minimal polynomial $m_A(t)$, and conversely... (you finish the argument)